# windows phone 8 background agent

Tags: background, windows-phone-8, task

With Windows Phone 8 like Lumia 920, there is a page in Settings/Applications. Click on the "background tasks", it lists some of applications I installed. I can config them to allow or blocked. I assume that those enabled app can run in background when I switch to other app. I am developing a music player. I need this feature. So, for example I am listening my playlist. The music plays to end and then stopped after I pressed Home button and switched to other app. It is because my process can't listen the play-end event. Can anyone tell me what I can do to keep my logic running. Is it using so called background agent? Is it automatically shows up in background task page? Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Add WindowsPhoneAudioPlaybackAgent to your project, and use it to play music. Here is a manual 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202978(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Hi, I can't use it unfortunately. It is because it does not have API to read songs from media library. I can only use MediaPlayer and MediaLibrary APIs to play songs one by one.

Comment: You can pass playlist with songs to agent via xml. The sample you can find in Charles Petzold's book Programming Windows Phone 7. Here the link http://www.charlespetzold.com/phone/index.html

Comment: Thanks. But I think this background audio player can't play music from MediaLibrary, right? It needs to specify path of the songs that you copied your way. If you transfer music through Zune or or whatever WP8 has supported, it is automatically harvested to MediaLibrary that you have no idea where it went.

Comment: You can try to get the tracks from medialibary, then serialise this collection to some file in isostorage, and in agent deserialize this file into collection of audoitracks. A didn't try it, but it may works.

Answer (score 1):

Got answer from this link. It works well. My App is listed in the Background tasks/Settings.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202941%28v=vs.105%29.aspx